# Laravel Error : The GET method is not supported for route addproduct. Supported methods: POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Im a beginner in laravel. I got problem try posting to route. i don't use any form (form action="" Method="POST"). I think the problem might be in my controller.

This is my button:

```html
<div class="button0">
  <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-primary"
    style="margin:20px 150px 0 0; float: right; width:100px" 
    id="btnInsert"
  >
    Insert
  </button>
</div>
```

Here's my script:

```js
$("#btnInsert").click(function () {
  var productid = $("#productid").val();
  var productname = $("#productname").val();
  var productprice = $("#productprice").val();
  var productdes = $("#productdes").val();
  var productimage = $("#productimage").val();
  var productcate = $("#cate").val();

  if (productid == "") {
    alert("Empty Product ID");
  } else {
    // it doesn't work after this

    $.post("/addproduct", {
      productid: productid,
      productname: productname,
      productprice: productprice,
      productdes: productdes,
      productimage: productimage,
      productcate: productcate,
    }),
      function (result) {
        if (result == 1) {
          alert("Record has been added");
          window.location.href = "/product";
        }
      };
  }
});
```

this is my route:

```php
Route::post('/addproduct',[ProductController::class, 'AddProduct']);
```

this is my controller, There might be some incorrect here.

```php
public function AddProduct(Request $request){
        try{
            $productid = $request->productid ;
            $productname = $request->productname;
            $productprice = $request->productprice;
            $productdes = $request->productdes;
            $productimage = $request->productimage;
            $categoryid = $request->categoryid; 
            $result = DB::table('tblproduct')->insert(['ProductID'=>$productid, 
            'ProductName'=>$productname, 
            'ProductPrice'=>$productprice, 
            'ProductDes'=>$productdes, 
            'ProductImage'=>$productimage, 
            'CategoryID'=>$categoryid]);
            if ($result) {
            return redirect()->route('product.InsertProduct');
            } else {
            echo "Insert failed: " . DB::getErrorMessage();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $ex){
        echo ($ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: are there any other route in your web/api that uses `addproduct`? maybe it recognized the first route before your intended route.

Comment: i only use addproduct once. here is my other routes:
Route::post('/addproduct',[ProductController::class, 'AddProduct']);
Route::post('/deleteproduct',[ProductController::class, 'DeleteProduct'])->name('product.InsertProduct');
Route::post('/updateproduct',[ProductController::class, 'UpdateProduct']);
Route::get('/product',[ProductController::class, 'ListProduct']);

Comment: @Phil No, i dont use any form. This is my button.
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin:20px 150px 0 0; float: right; width:100px" id="btnInsert">Insert</button>

Comment: FYI you have a typo. The _success_ function is meant to be passed into the `$.post()` parameters but yours is outside. It should be `$.post('/addproduct', { ... }, function (result) { ... })`

Comment: Now that you have `type="button"`, does it change the behaviour?

Comment: @Phil sorry it's my first time using stackoverflow. yes i just change. i did change my typo but the error still the same

Comment: Please [edit] your question to match your current code

Comment: That is not the error you claim in your question. If you're getting a 500 response, check your server's error log

Comment: @Phil the title error i  get it from page (http://127.0.0.1:8000/product), but the comment error i seen when i inspect the console.

Comment: sue name routes and check  ex `Route::post('/addproduct',[ProductController::class, 'AddProduct'])->name('addproduct');`

Comment: kindly upload form code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all hit these artisan commands:

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

or you can use

```
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan optimize
```

and after that correct your url: coz apis in api.php file
like

```
$.post("api/addproduct", {
```

Hope , It will helps you

Answer (score 0):

Your method is also good , but as you say you are beginner so i recommend you must read laravel documentation and practicing the MVC methodology.

**Always Use Naming Routes, and make sure every route has different or unique name or you may create group of route**

**Naming Route**

```
Add Controller in web.php | api.php on top.


use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;

Route::post('/addproduct', [ProductController::class, 'AddProduct'])->name('add.product');
```

**Group Route**

```
 Route::controller(ProductController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::post('/addproduct','AddProduct')->name('add.product');
    Route::get('/listproduct','ListProduct')->name('list.product');
});
```

```html
<form action="{{ route('add.product') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                                autocomplete="off">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="row">
                                    
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                        <label for="horizontal-main-course-input"
                                                            class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">Name</label>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
                                                                id="name" placeholder="Enter Name Here">

                                                            @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                                                <span
                                                                    class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>
                                                            @endif
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                        <label for="horizontal-main-course-input"
                                                            class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">Email</label>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price"
                                                                id="price"
                                                                placeholder="Enter Price Here">

                                                            @if ($errors->has('price'))
                                                                <span
                                                                    class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('price') }}</span>
                                                            @endif
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align: center;">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-md">SAVE</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

**Create Controller:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        // Logic to display a list of products
    }

    public function create()
    {
        // Return a view for creating a new product
        return view('products.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate and store the product
        $product = new Product();
        // Assign values from $request to $product properties
        $product->productid = $request->input('productid');
        $product->productname = $request->input('productname');
        // ... other properties
        $product->save();

        // Redirect to the products index page or do something else
        return redirect()->route('products.index');
    }
}
```

Create model `Product`and migration to connect or save data in table.
I hope this will help you or you may ask anything you want.
Happy Coding!

Comment: Hi i just update my controller can u take a look at them.

Comment: Sure, show me the code, and I'll help you.

Comment: I did edit my post

Answer (score 0):

your Laravel codes are fine, but you have a problem with your JS code.

you forgot to use the **done** callback function after post request.

```
$.post("/addproduct", {
productid: productid,
productname: productname,
productprice: productprice,
productdes: productdes,
productimage: productimage,
productcate: productcate,
}).done(function (result) {
  if (result == 1) {
    alert("Record has been added");
    window.location.href = "/product";
  }
});
```

hope it will help you